# How to Auto Capture an Image from Camera, when the camera is focused in flutter?

Tags: flutter, camera

I have tried the following function, that captures at a duration of 3 seconds.

We do not need to add a timer for capturing an image.
We need to capture only when its focused.

MyCode :

```
captureImage() async {
    // Obtain a list of available cameras
    List<CameraDescription> cameras = await availableCameras();

    setState(() {
      showCamera = true;
    });

    // Initialize the camera
    controller = CameraController(
      cameras[0],
      ResolutionPreset.high,
    );
    await controller?.initialize();

    /// Capture Image in 5 seconds
    const captureInterval = Duration(seconds: 3);

    Timer.periodic(captureInterval, (timer) async {

      // Take a picture
      final image = await controller?.takePicture();

      // Save the image to the device storage
      final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      final imagePath = '${directory.path}/image.jpg';
      await image?.saveTo(imagePath);
      File imageFile = File(imagePath);

      Uint8List imagebytes = await imageFile.readAsBytes(); //convert to bytes
      Base64Image = base64.encode(imagebytes); //convert bytes to base64 string

      timer.cancel();

    });

  }
```